# Hosting a site on Github and Heroku with custom domain name

Tags: github, heroku, namecheap

Apologies if this question seems very simple, but I am new to the web-hosting world, and have a slight dilemma. I started off by hosting a single-page website on Github pages with a custom domain.

I then decided to add two static pages, as well as two dynamic pages (all supposed to be linked to one-another, and the two dynamic pages have separate databases). The pages are all in their separate repositories, on Github, and on Heroku for the two dynamic pages. The pages all work with their generated domain names (such as `username.github.io/static_page1`).

What I want is to have all the pages with the custom domain name (for example, the index page would be `custom_domain.com`, and the static pages will be something like `custom_domain.com/static_page1` while the dynamic pages will be something like `custom_domain.com/dynamic_page1`).

I was wondering how one would go about doing this on Github Pages and Heroku (my domain provider is Namecheap). I've been lurking on numerous posts and tutorials, but I could not find a solution :(